# How to pass table name value(parameter) with x-editable textbox?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, x-editable

I want to pass one extra value that is table name with the data pass to post.php
currently name,value,pk are three field pass in that file..

```
<span class="edit_title" data-type="text" data-name="title" data-url="post.php" data-pk="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?= $row['title']; ?></span>

jQuery('.edit_title').editable({
        validate: function(value) {
            if($.trim(value) == '') return 'This field is required';
        }
    });
```

And how i get these value in php file ???????